# Visual Studio Form to start a Rich Discord Presence when run

Tags: discord

I'm trying to make a Visual Studio Form that I can publish. I want it to start a custom Discord Rich Presence when it's running. How do I do this?

Comment: Please add further details to your question for example: what have you tried so far, what errors are you facing upon them, what research have you done upon the topic, etc.

Comment: I didn't do anything really. I didn't find an answer in stack yet so I'm just hoping for help because I have no idea how to do it :/

Comment: Sorry Professor Puddle, Stackoverflow is not a code writing service although I'd surely guide you to the adequate resources, creating an answer now.

Comment: Alright. Cool. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was amused to see such a vast question and it wasn't focused to a point so I'd frame this answer upon focusing on creating a visual studio extension for rich presence in discord, to start creating an extension you can refer to [this guide](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/get-started/your-first-extension) further integrate it with the Discord API , since it provides an endpoint for it and offers methods for it, you can read more about it [here](https://discord.com/developers/docs/rich-presence/how-to#rich-presence-field-requirements), although again this is a very extensive and time consuming task so I suggest using pre-made extensions for your visual studio code available in the extension marketplace, one such extension is [Discord Rich Presence Extension By iCrawl](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=icrawl.discord-vscode) it is absolutely Open Source and is from an experienced developer, the creator of discord.js

Comment: Glad it helped!  make sure to add an upvote using the  button and accept the answer using ✓ icon, refer to [what to do when someone answers my question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) for more info!

Comment: sure. I don't I can upvote because I'm new but I accepted the answer :D